# How can i redirect a clickable item in list view to some other activity?

Tags: android

I want to link my items present in list view to some other activity, so that i can move to some other activity on clicking a list view item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use like this

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, Categories));
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id) {

          switch (position){
          case 0: Intent animalsGridViewIntent = new Intent(ListOfAppGallery.this,AnimalsGridView.class);     
                  ListOfAppGallery.this.startActivity(animalsGridViewIntent);
                  break;
          case 1: Intent calenderGridViewIntent = new Intent(ListOfAppGallery.this,CalenderGridView.class);     
                  ListOfAppGallery.this.startActivity(calenderGridViewIntent);
                  break;
          case 2: Intent carsGridViewIntent = new Intent(ListOfAppGallery.this,CarsGridView.class);     
                  ListOfAppGallery.this.startActivity(carsGridViewIntent);
                  break;
          }
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

add `list.setOnItemClickListener(this);` for ListView and implenment OnItemClickListener for an activity.

and override this method to another activity:

@Override

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, final int position,long arg3) 
  {
  Intent in=new Intent(YourActivity.this,NewClass.class);
            startActivity(in);
             finish();

  }
```

check the position accordingly you want